# Regular expression: exclusion

Tags: regex

I want to exclude a specific pattern from a multi-line text field. I have a regular expression that catches that pattern so now I want to make an expression that matches everything except this pattern. What would be a general approach to this? For some reason negative lookahead like this: `^(.(?!expression))*$` doesn't work for me.

Comment: can you provide some sample input?

Comment: You know that it will match everything but that exact pattern? So if you want to match the word tree in the sentence "the tree in the forest" it will have allot of different options that would match but only the exact match for tree would fail.. So it is more effective, depending on your goal, to match positive and discard it when there is a match.

Comment: You may be using the wrong approach here.  if by exclude you mean you want to filter it out, I'd suggest using your pattern with a find/replace function and just replace with an empty string.

Comment: What language are you using? If linux commandline you can just use the `-v` flag with `grep`.

Answer (score 3):

## Description

`^(?!.*?\btest\b)`

[image]

This will search the string looking for `test`, and if exists in the string then the test will fail. [See also sample](http://www.rubular.com/r/sJ6VXjb0oI)

## Summary

- `^` match the beginning of the string
- `(?!`                      look ahead to see if there is not:
- `.*?`                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
- `\b`                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                           and something that is not a word char
- `test`                    match `test`
- `\b`                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                           and something that is not a word char
- `)`                        end of look-ahead

Comment: Weird... ok i updated this so it'll work on rubular, and included a sample link

Answer (score 2):

You just have the dot in the wrong place.  You need to do the lookahead *before* you consume the next character, not after:

```
^(?:(?!expression).)*$
```

Also, if there can be line-separators in the string, you need to specify multiline/DOTALL mode.  How you do that depends on the regex flavor you're using.  Some examples:

```
(?s)^(?:(?!expression).)*$

/^(?:(?!expression).)*$/s

^(?:(?!expression)[\s\S])*$
```

Or you can use [Denomales' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400971/denomales), which is a little easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this expression working for me:

```
^.*(?=expression)
```

where `expression` represents a regular expression matching the pattern I wanna exclude.
I recommend this tool for testing - http://gskinner.com/RegExr/